# how to store the pdf file to folder in codeigntier using tcpdf

Tags: codeigniter

using tcpdf for generated the pdf file in codeigniter. I want to store the pdf file in specific folder for the purpose of mail attachment. After generated it display the blank page.  How to correct this issue.  Please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i ever used in my codeigniter projects:

```
/application
/system
/assets
   /css
   /js
/uploads
```

store your pdf file in uploads directory in your application's root folder, with a unique name or whatever you like

Comment: just i store the pdf like you say, My issue is after save the file a new blank page is open.